# Play framework 1.x with java 8

Tags: playframework-1.x, java-8

How can I make `play framework 1.x` work with Java 8?

Play framework version `1.2.5.3`

```
Java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

I have an error:

> play.exceptions.CompilationException: java.util.stream.Collectors
>   cannot be resolved    at
>   play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler$2.acceptResult(ApplicationCompiler.java:246)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.handleInternalException(Compiler.java:676)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:520)
>     at
>   play.classloading.ApplicationCompiler.compile(ApplicationCompiler.java:282)
>     at
>   play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.compile(ApplicationClasses.java:281)
>     at
>   play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.detectChanges(ApplicationClassloader.java:324)
>     at play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:625)   at
>   play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:198)    at Invocation.HTTP
>   Request(Play!)

Comment: AFAIK the java stream api has been rebuild. Very few chances, Play will work out of the box with Java 8. Probably wait for the next update.

Comment: I hope it will be soon

Comment: play is using the eclipse compiler under the hood `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler`, that has a different version and perhaps jdk to your main 1.8 install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a commit in the repository for java 8 support with play 1.3

https://github.com/playframework/play1/blob/master/framework/src/play/classloading/ApplicationCompiler.java