# Play framework 1.2.7.x with Java 1.8

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

Is Play framework 1.2.7 supported with java 1.8? I am able to precompile the application but it fails with the following error on start

```
@6o4d1jh71
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /

Oops: UnexpectedException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.ContinuationEnhancer on helpers.CheatSheetHelper$2

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying play.CorePlugin@6b0c2d26 on helpers.CheatSheetHelper$2
        at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:566)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.enhance(ApplicationClasses.java:235)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:167)
        at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:431)
        at play.Play.start(Play.java:526)
        at play.Play.detectChanges(Play.java:640)
        at play.Invoker$Invocation.init(Invoker.java:198)
        at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.ContinuationEnhancer on helpers.CheatSheetHelper$2
        at play.CorePlugin.enhance(CorePlugin.java:302)
        at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:561)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
        at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:203)
        at javassist.CtClassType.subtypeOf(CtClassType.java:303)
        at javassist.CtClassType.subtypeOf(CtClassType.java:318)
        at play.classloading.enhancers.ContinuationEnhancer.enhanceThisClass(ContinuationEnhancer.java:49)
        at play.CorePlugin.enhance(CorePlugin.java:297)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1027)
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:970)
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:127)
        at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:693)
        at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:85)
        at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:190)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer is coming to late but...
   As far as I know there's no java 8support for 1.2.X but following this answer: [Play framework 1.x with java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930366/play-framework-1-x-with-java-8][1])
You could easily move to 1.3 and use that solution. I just did a migration from 1.2 to 1.4 without big issues.